# ./pintos run alarm-multiple command not creating threads

Tags: operating-system, ubuntu-18.04, qemu, pintos

I have ubuntu version 18.04.3 running on virtual box. 
I have been trying to install pintos on qemu,  but when I run `./pintos run alarm-multiple` my qemu is stuck on loading.
I am getting the following output:

> **WARNING: Image format was not specified for '/tmp/5XpQ2ee16J.dsk' and probing guessed raw.
>
> Automatically detecting the format is dangerous for raw images, write
>   operations on block 0 will be restricted.Specify the 'raw' format
>   explicitly to remove the restrictions.
>
> qemu-system-x86_64: warning: TCG doesn't support requested feature:
>
> CPUID.01H:ECX.vmx [bit 5]
>
> PiLo hda1
>
> Loading............
>
> Kernel command line: run alarm-multiple
>
> Pintos booting with**

Nothing is coming after **pintos booting with**

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old version of pintos.
Use the latest version available here.

git://pintos-os.org/pintos-anon

Comment: This seems like a comment rather than an answer. With a bit more reputation points, [you will be able to post comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). [Good article](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/) about answering questions.